# VBScript alternative/conversion?

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a piece of code from a long time ago and am trying to integrate it into HTML5. It's written in VBScript, which is no longer supported, and I want to change it into something understood by modern browsers. This was originally part of an HTA file, but everything in it works fine in HTML5 except this script. Any help would be appreciated.

The code:

```vb
</style>
<font color="#FF0000" size="+3"><marquee>Marquee Text Here</marquee></font>
<script language="vbscript">
Public n, iTimerID, MyTitle, colnum, carset
ReDim M(1,1)
ReDim SpecCar(64)
SpecCar(0)="&permil;" 
SpecCar(1)="&fnof;"   : SpecCar(11)="&Omega;"   : SpecCar(21)="&lambda;" : SpecCar(31)="&phi;"
SpecCar(2)="&Gamma;"  : SpecCar(12)="&alpha;"   : SpecCar(22)="&mu;"     : SpecCar(32)="&psi;"
SpecCar(3)="&Delta;"  : SpecCar(13)="&beta;"    : SpecCar(23)="&nu;"     : SpecCar(33)="&omega;"
SpecCar(4)="&Theta;"  : SpecCar(14)="&delta;"   : SpecCar(24)="&xi;"     : SpecCar(34)="&trade;"
SpecCar(5)="&Lambda;" : SpecCar(15)="&epsilon;" : SpecCar(25)="&pi;"     : SpecCar(35)="&larr;"
SpecCar(6)="&Xi;"     : SpecCar(16)="&zeta;"    : SpecCar(26)="&rho;"    : SpecCar(36)="&uarr;"
SpecCar(7)="&Pi;"     : SpecCar(17)="&eta;"     : SpecCar(27)="&sigmaf;" : SpecCar(37)="&rarr;"
SpecCar(8)="&Sigma;"  : SpecCar(19)="&iota;"    : SpecCar(29)="&tau;"    : SpecCar(39)="&harr;"
SpecCar(10)="&Psi;"   : SpecCar(20)="&kappa;"   : SpecCar(30)="&upsilon;": SpecCar(40)="&radic;"
SpecCar(41)="&infin;" : SpecCar(46)="&there4;"  : SpecCar(51)="&ge;"     : SpecCar(56)="&clubs;"
SpecCar(42)="&ang;"   : SpecCar(47)="&asymp;"   : SpecCar(52)="&oplus;"  : SpecCar(57)="&hearts;"
SpecCar(43)="&cap;"   : SpecCar(48)="&ne;"      : SpecCar(53)="&perp;"   : SpecCar(58)="&diams;"
SpecCar(44)="&cup;"   : SpecCar(49)="&equiv;"   : SpecCar(54)="&loz;"    : SpecCar(59)="&OElig;"
SpecCar(45)="&int;"   : SpecCar(50)="&le;"      : SpecCar(55)="&spades;" : SpecCar(60)="&dagger;"
SpecCar(61)="&Dagger;": SpecCar(62)="&euro;"    : SpecCar(63)="&oelig;"  : SpecCar(64)="&Scaron;"

Sub window_onLoad()
    n = 48
    colnum = 100
    carset = 1
    ReDim M(colnum,1)
    ' Set a random number for the first character 
    ' to be written on the screen for each column 
    ' (div). This is useful to avoid all the
    ' column to start at the same place 
    For i=1 To colnum
        Randomize                                   '---This formula doesn't accept variables
        M(i,0) = Int(n*Rnd)                         '--- M(i,0) contains the number of the character to be written
        t = ""
                                                    '--- Fill the column with white space
        For j=1 To n
            t = t & "&nbsp;<br>"
        Next
        M(i,1) = t                                  '--- M(i,1) contains the html of the column
    Next
    iTimerID = window.setInterval("Progress", 300)
End Sub

Sub Progress
    For i=1 To colnum
        l = Split(M(i,1), "<br>")                   '--- split by each character in the column
        cpos = M(i,0)                               '--- position of the character to be written on the screen at this time
                                                    '--- write a random ascii or a character from the array 
        Randomize
        If Int(carset) = 1 Then
            l(cpos) = "<span style=""color:GreenYellow"">" & Chr( 32 + Int(223*Rnd) ) & "</span>"
            carset = carset +0.25
        ElseIf Int(carset) = 2 Then
            l(cpos) = "<span style=""color:GreenYellow"">" & SpecCar( Int(64*Rnd) )  & "</span>"
            carset = 1
        End If
                                                    '--- scale down to dark the previous characters
        y = -1
        For j = cpos-1 To cpos-11 Step -1
            tempj = j
            If j < 0 Then                           '--- when we start from the top, darken characters at the bottom
                j = UBound(l) +j +1
            End If
            y = y + 1
            Select Case y
                Case 0 color="LawnGreen"
                Case 1 color="LawnGreen"
                Case 2 color="LimeGreen"
                Case 3 color="LimeGreen"
                Case 4 color="ForestGreen"
                Case 5 color="ForestGreen"
                Case 6 color="Green"
                Case 7 color="Green"
                Case 8 color="DarkGreen"
                Case 9 color="DarkGreen"
                Case 10 color=""
            End Select
            clj = l(j)
            If InStr(1, clj, "<span", 1) > 0 Then   '--- isolate the character from the span tag
                clj = Left(clj, InStrRev(clj, "<") - 1)
                clj = Mid(clj, InStr(clj, ">") + 1)
            End If
            If color <> "" Then                     '--- set a span with a color style only if necessary
                l(j) = "<span style=""color:" & color & """>" & clj & "</span>"
            Else
                l(j) = clj
            End If
            j = tempj
        Next
        t = Join(l, "<br>")
        M(i,1) = t                                  '--- M(i,1) contains the html of the column
        cpos = cpos +1
        If cpos > UBound(l) Then
            cpos = 0
        End If
        M(i,0) = cpos                               '--- M(i,0) contains the number of the character to be written
        id("col" & i).innerHTML = t                 '--- Show the result for this the column on the screen
    Next
End Sub

Sub ExitMatrix
    window.clearInterval(iTimerID)                  '---You must always clear the intervals before leaving
    window.close
End Sub

Function id(o)
    Set id = document.getElementById(o)
End Function
</script>
```

Comment: For client-side web code JavaScript is the language of choice. Translating the script for you is way beyond the scope of SO, though.

Comment: I managed to get the script running in an old version of IE. As expected, it seems to be some cheap copy of a 'The Matrix' style animation. Are you sure you want to bring it back? :D